# Python can't see import file

Tags: python, flask

I am building a web application in Python Flask. In my **init** file, I am importing a .py file named create. The init file cannot find the create file. Both files are in the same directory.

```
import os

from flask import Flask, request, render_template
from create import createBP

def create_app(test_config=None):
   # create and configure the app
    app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=True)
    app.register_blueprint(createBP)
```

The error that I am receiving: No module named 'create'.

Comment: The current working directory is not a default component of the Python path; only the directory that contains the script being executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should import it as `module_name.create`.

For example if you module name is `app`

```
from app.create import createBP
```